# Any recover from sudo chmod 600 /

Tags: chmod

I was configuring ssl certificate on server and while following documentation I accidentally pasted terminal command without checking.

```
sudo chmod 600 / usr/local/nginx/ssl/my-ssl.key
```

It immediately kicked me out of the server because I guess this result in changing permissions of ubuntu root folder. What can I do?

EDIT: I used chmod not chown command

Comment: You did NOT use -R? Then yes should be simple. 1 moment. and you are sure you did `chown 600` and not `chmod 600`?

Comment: @Rinzwind I didn't use recursive -R flag and you are right I used chmod not chwon

Comment: no problem :) see if my edit is good enough. You might need to fix some stuff in your / that I do not have.

Comment: oh lol sorry cant stop laughing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In case `sudo` does not work this needs to be done from a live session.

If this is a cloud instance you need to go to the cloud console, create a new instance, mount your disk in the new instance and then fix it on the mountpoint. After that re-attach the disk to boot from it.

Everything in `/` except for mountpoints is set to `root` so this will revert your command:

```
sudo chown root /
```

Then do a

```
sudo chown $USER {mountpoints}
```

for every mountpoint you have.

---

edit: When using `chmod`:

```
sudo chmod 777 /lib*/ /tmp/ /sbin/ /bin/
sudo chmod 770 /cdrom/ 
sudo chmod 750 /usr/ /sys/ /srv/ /snap/ /run/ /proc/ /opt/ /mnt/ 
sudo chmod 750 /media/ /home/ /etc/ /dev/ /boot/ 
sudo chmod 700 /root/ /lost+found/
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
```

In case I missed anything this it what it should look like:

```
drwxr-xr-x  14 root     root           4096 mrt 30  2022 usr
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root           4096 mrt 30  2022 srv
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root           4096 mrt 30  2022 mnt
drwxr-xr-x  14 root     root           4096 mrt 30  2022 var
drwx------   2 root     root          16384 apr  3  2022 lost+found
-rw-------   1 root     root     1942548480 apr  3  2022 swapfile
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root              8 apr  3  2022 sbin -> usr/sbin
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root             10 apr  3  2022 libx32 -> usr/libx32
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root              9 apr  3  2022 lib64 -> usr/lib64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root              9 apr  3  2022 lib32 -> usr/lib32
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root              7 apr  3  2022 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root              7 apr  3  2022 bin -> usr/bin
drwxrwxr-x   2 root     root           4096 apr  3  2022 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root           4096 apr  3  2022 home
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root           4096 apr  8 20:29 media
drwxr-xr-x  14 root     root           4096 apr 18 08:35 snap
drwx------   7 root     root           4096 jul 18 20:33 root
drwxr-xr-x   4 root     root           4096 sep 21 06:36 boot
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root     root              0 okt  3 23:23 sys
dr-xr-xr-x 378 root     root              0 okt  3 23:23 proc
drwxr-xr-x  36 root     root            960 okt  4 17:29 run
drwxr-xr-x 143 root     root          12288 okt  4 17:30 etc
drwxr-xr-x   6 root     root           4096 okt  4 17:53 opt
drwxr-xr-x  19 root     root           4800 okt  4 18:49 dev
drwxrwxrwt  35 root     root           4096 okt  4 23:24 tmp
```

edit:

And you also need to do

```
sudo chmod 600 /usr/local/nginx/ssl/my-ssl.key
```

;)

Comment: How is running anything possible after `chmod 600 /`?

Comment: But how can he even access `/sbin/sudo` (or whatever the path is) if he lacks execute rights to `/`?

Comment: I am not going to test it on  my machine ;-) so I added a live session option :D

Comment: @OskarSkog Nothing on the system is going to work unless running as root (overriding DAC), so you're right that sudo is not the answer (the chown effectively disabled all non-root users). This is where an actual root login would come in handy. Assuming OP can't just ssh in as root, it means rebooting and fixing it from initramfs, or `init=/bin/sh`, or just launching a shell as root if this is a container.

Comment: BTW, as OP didn't use `-R`, there's no point trying to fix permissions/ownership on mountpoints or essentially anything except for `/` (as nothing else got touched). The answer could thus be trimmed down considerably.

Comment: @TooTea -the contents of the mp- need to be changed.

Comment: @Rinzwind Sorry, I don't understand that comment. My point is that OP only ran `chmod 0600 /`, which changes the permissions on the root directory `/` itself, not on anything contained in it. Reverting it is thus only about changing the permissions on that one directory.

Comment: no it is the contents of that one directory.

Comment: @Rinzwind This would be true if he had used `sudo chmod 600 /*`. Indeed, it is only the one directory entry which represents `/`. You can try this out in a chroot.